# client side validation not working for uniqueness method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid, client-side-validation

validates_uniqueness_of is not working in my rails with for Client_side_validation gem. I am using MongoID and devise

this is my code

```
/user.rb

  validates_presence_of :name, :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :name ,:email
```

/form

```
%h2 Sign up
= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name,
       :url => registration_path(resource_name),
       :html => {:id => "sign_up_user"},
       :validate => true ,
       :remote => true) do |f|

  %div
    =f.label :name
    %br
    =f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true
  %div
    = f.label :email
    %br/
    = f.email_field :email
  %div
    = f.label :password
    %br/
    = f.password_field :password
  %div
    = f.label :password_confirmation
    %br/
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation
  %div= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'btn btn-success btn-medium'
```

UPDATE* This is the error response from the browser console

Request URL:http:..../validators/uniqueness?case_sensitive=false&user%5Bname%5D=jesus&_=1385056603510
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Validating uniqueness makes an AJAX request. Could you open js console and paste its results?

Comment: ok, i update my question , the browser returns 500 http error status,

Comment: Now you should be able to click on this error, select html view and see error message together with stack. :)

Comment: You may need to add your custom validator, check this thread: https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations/issues/710